# @Transactional (noRollbackFor=RuntimeException.class) does not prevent rollback on RuntimeException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

```
@Transactional (noRollbackFor=RuntimeException.class)
public void methodA (Entity e){
   service.methodB(e);
}
```

---service method below---

```
@Transactional (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor=RuntimeException.class)
public void methodB (Entity e){
   dao.insert(e);
}
```

When `dao.insert(e)` in `methodB()` causes a primary key violation and throws a `ConstraintViolationException`, which is a subclass of `RuntimeException`, I would expect the transaction to still commit because of the `noRollbackFor` property I used. But I observed that the outer transaction (on `methodA`) is still being rolled back by the `HibernateTransactionManager` with the message

> org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollback Exception:
>   Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

I've found similar questions reported but not exactly this one.

Comment: Did you set globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure to false E.g. `<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure" value="false" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>`

Comment: pretty sure sol4me is on the right track - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11205537/1594449

Comment: Sounds like a great idea but I am not keen to change the setting of `globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure` because I am enhancing an existing monolithic piece of code that already uses the same transaction manager, and I would want to keep the existing code unaffected by my change - this does not appear feasible by changing the tx manager config. 
Can I do something that will be entirely specific to my change?

Comment: just for your information, I also tried catching the `RuntimeException` thrown in `dao.insert(e);` within `methodB` and rethrowing it out after wrapping it in a checked exception. I changed the `noRollbackFor` to match the checked exception used. However, this made no difference - the outer transaction in `methodA` was still rolled back!

Comment: are `methodA` and `MethodB` on the same object/service?

Comment: @ThermalEagle how is the transaction started/propagated for `methodA`, Also have a look at the queries being fired at the back, does `method A` is trying to insert something as well during flushing..??

Comment: @ankur-singhal - would it matter who starts the transaction for methodA since methodB is starting a new transaction?

Comment: @AndyDufresne yes, it does not matter since `methodB` starts its own transaction,

Comment: Is the `dao.insert(e)` annotated with `@Transactional`? If so, it should also have `noRollbackFor` to not mark whole transaction to rollback.

Answer (score 32):

Once an exception is caught, the [Hibernate Session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) should be discarded and the transaction should be rolled back:

> If the Session throws an exception, the transaction must be rolled
>   back and the session discarded. The internal state of the Session
>   might not be consistent with the database after the exception occurs.

So, `noRollbackFor` applies to your Service and DAO layer that might throw an exception. Let's say you have a **gatewayService** that write to a Database through a Hibernate DAO and also sends an email through an **emailService**. If the emailService throws a `SendMailFailureException` you can instruct the **gatewayService** not to roll back when it will catch this exception:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=SendMailFailureException.class)
public void saveAndSend(Entity e){
   dao.save(e);
   emailService.send(new Email(e));
}
```

Comment: Well explained with an example

Comment: @AndyDufresne what my understanding is - `Method B` has its own transaction, method A transaction will be suspended , so as proxy, proxy called it `target method method B`, and if any exception occurs for which `no rollback` is configured, only this transaction will be take care of, then it will resume the transaction of `method A`

Comment: Even if there's a new transaction because of Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, the same principle applies to the Hibernate Session.

Comment: @VladMihalcea so `noRollBackFor` works only for exceptions that are not database\hibernate specific ones? So say `DataIntegrityViolationException`  will rollback in any case? Also as I understand even having `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` will not help as hibernate will mark all suspended transaction in the chain as rollback-only, because hibernate marks whole Session as rollback?

Comment: That's right. You can use it for when the cache is not available, but you could still serve the request from the DB.

Comment: @VladMihalcea looks like `propagation.not_supported` did the trick. Original transaction gets suspended, and is not going to roll back even if method marked with `not_supported` throws `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

Comment: Very interesting use case. You should write an article about it. I'm interested in reading more about it.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I first resist to use it like feeling a bit cheating. Then, I read the example and convinced. My case was, reset password token expired (no scheduler used for the sake of performance) but status still seems to be legit. I first check if token, if status legit but date expired; then update token to status expired too and  throw exception (AlreadyUsedException) for client to take appropriate action. Without this property it was failing.