# @Transactional noRollbackFor EmptyResultDataAccessException.class is not working

Tags: spring-data, spring-transactions

I would like to ignore the exception and commit the transaction anyway. However, every time I get a error. What exactly is the problem and how can I solve it?

```
@Transactional( noRollbackFor = EmptyResultDataAccessException.class )
   public Foo foo( Foo foo, String barId ) {
    Foo foo = fooRepository.save(foo)
    deleteBarSilently(barId)
      return foo ;
   }


   //@Transactional( noRollbackFor = EmptyResultDataAccessException.class )
   private void deleteBarSilently( final String barId) {

      try {
         barRepository.deleteById( barId);
      } catch ( final EmptyResultDataAccessException ignored ) {
         System.out.println( ignored );
      }
   }
```

Error is: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction "rolled back" because transaction was set to RollbackOnly.

Exception is EmptyResultDataAccessException

EDIT: Also tried it with try/catch and without and with a array of exception
@Transactional( noRollbackFor = {EmptyResultDataAccessException.class} )
and with fullqualified class name

Log without catch

```
Application exception overridden by commit exception

org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class com.bosch.bci.foundation.digitaltwin.repository.domain.ModelReference entity with id c16675da-f5ce-46b1-97e6-7eb6869940aa exists!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.lambda$deleteById$0(SimpleJpaRepository.java:166) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
```

Log with catch is just

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction "rolled back" because transaction was set to RollbackOnly.
```

Answer (score 2):

[`noRollbackFor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#noRollbackFor--) expects an array of Throwable subclasses instead you are passing only a class (`EmptyResultDataAccessException`)

Try changing to (note the curly braces "{" and "}" which signify the array):

```
@Transactional( noRollbackFor = { EmptyResultDataAccessException.class })
```

***UPDATE***

It seems that since `EmptyResultDataAccessException` is a `RuntimeException` trying not to rollback upon hitting it is not a case, unless you globally set `globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure=false`.

**Solution 1**

The first solution is to implement your own `barRepository.deleteById( barId)` which does not throw `EmptyResultDataAccessException`

e.g.

in your `BarRepository` create the following method:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM Bar b WHERE b.id= :id")
void customDeleteById(Long id);
```

and in your `deleteBarSilently` remove the `try catch` and simply have:

```
@Transactional
private void deleteBarSilently( final Long barId) {
     barRepository.customDeleteById( barId);
}
```

**Solution 2**

In the second solution you can change your code to the following to run the `deleteBarSilently` outside of the transaction of `foo` so when you hit the `EmptyResultDataAccessException` simply `try catch` it and no rollback will occur.

Firstly you need to separate your methods to different services (for `@Transactional` annotation to work), lets say `FooService` and `BarService`,

**FooService**

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BarService barService;

    @Transactional
    public Student foo( Foo foo, Long barId ) {
        Foo savedFoo = fooRepository.save(foo);
        barService.deleteBarSilently(barId);
        return savedFoo ;
    }
}
```

**BarService**

Annotate the method with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` which will cause the transaction to suspend, execute the method's code outside of transaction and then resume.

```
@Service
public class BarService {

    @Autowired
    private BarRepository barRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void deleteBarSilently( final Long barId) {
        try {
            barRepository.deleteById( barId);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that makes no difference. I've already tested that. I've also tried it with and without try / catch.

Comment: Yeah no luck with `noRollbackFor`. I have updated my answer with 2 possible solutions that I have tested and they work, please have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I know both solutions, but I don't like them.

The third option is to call findById(barId).ifPresent(em: remove) so that no exception happens. You can add this solution as well in your post. Then i think all solutions are in one post.

2 questions:
1. Is there a note in the documentation that I overlooked that no RuntimeExeptions work? Most exceptions are runtime exceptions, aren't they?Is there a reason for the restriction

2. Can I catch the RuntimeException and convert/rethrow a checked exception, which is specified in noRollbackFor. Would it work?

Comment: do you have some ideas or hint here?

Comment: Have you tried what I mentioned in my answer: "It seems that since `EmptyResultDataAccessException` is a `RuntimeException` trying not to rollback upon hitting it is not a case, unless you globally set `globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure=false`.". Have you set this property to `false` and see if `noRollbackFor` works as you want? I believe you can easily overcome your problem with applying either my suggestions or the ones in your comment above.

Comment: If you want to learn why it does not work as you expect, I believe the reason still is `globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure`, you can read more in relevant questions here in SO e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849968/transactional-norollbackfor-runtimeexception-class-does-not-prevent-rollback or try to debug into spring transaction internals. The rule however is: `Any RuntimeException triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does not.` https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings

Comment: I was just wondering or the documentation is misleading
'Any RuntimeException triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does not' but I understand: This is the default behavior and if I set the noRollbackFor i override the default the behavior.

Didn't try the globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure. I thought with globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure=false, the consequence is i have to handle all other exception manually to rollback the transaction? This was not my intention...